# How to calculate number of zeroes from 1 to a user given number and calculate time it took?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop, time

So, basically, what I need is to calculate the number of zeroes from 1 to a user given number. I need to ask them for a number, use a for-loop within a function to calculate the number of zeroes within that amount of numbers, print that back to them and then using the time() function, print how long it took to calculate. The desired output should look like this:

What number do you want to count zeros to? 10000

```
The number of zeros written from 1 to 10000 is 2893.
This took 0.0105922222137 seconds.
```

-This is what I have so far, it's very disoriented because I'm trying to tackle different pieces at once, which I realize is probably not the best way to approach it

```
 from time import time


 start_time =time()

stop_time = time()
elapsed = stop_time - start_time


def Count():
    i = 0'
    count = 0'
    for i in range(1,):
       if i % 10 is 0
            i = i + 1




x =
Num1 = input("What number do you want to count zeros to?: ")
print "The number of zeros written from 1 to {} is {}".format(Num1, x)
```

If anyone could be of assistance that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: you have lines in wrong order. If you want count time then you should get time at start and at the end but you take both times at start. if you get `Num1` then use it in `range(Num1)`. Number may have many zeros so using `i % 10` is useless. Better convert number to string and count char "0" in this string.

Comment: Consider taking log base 10 of the difference as a starting point

Comment: @furas, not completely true. You could use a `while` loop on each number and use `%` combined with `num //= 10` to pop digits off of the number

Comment: @C.Nivs you are right, code would need extra `while` loop. I'm wondering if it would run faster then converting to string but I will not test it :)

Comment: @furas it doesn't run faster than `str.count`, definitely due to the extra `while`, because it's still an O(N) check on each number, just like `str.count`

Answer (score 0):

The main trick with this problem is to start with counting the number of 0's, then move on to the timing. Think of the program structure as:

- Begin Timer
- Count 0's
- End Timer
- Display output

So to count the 0's, we might use loop over the range, which is just a list of numbers from the start to the end, so

```
range(0, 10)
```

is really just

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Therefore, we can loop through from the start(in this case 0), to the end(in this case 10000), which might look something like:

```
end = 10000
count = 0

for number in range(1, end + 1):
    count += str(number).count("0")
```

Then, we can add a timer using the time library, and print the result, so our code looks like this:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
end = 10000
count = 0

for number in range(1, end + 1):
    count += str(number).count("0")

print("The number of zeros written from 1 to " + str(end) + " is " + str(count) + ".")
print("This took %s seconds." % (time.time() - start_time))
```